# AWS Connect GetMetricData errors

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to call the AWS Connect GetMetricDataCommand endpoint with NodeJS

I am getting an error as below

```
Error fetching historical metrics: TypeError: _.getTime is not a function
    at EndTime (D:\Code\test\AWS-Dashboards\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-connect\dist-cjs\protocols\Aws_restJson1.js:1985:38)
    at applyInstruction (D:\Code\test\AWS-Dashboards\node_modules\@smithy\smithy-client\dist-cjs\object-mapping.js:73:33)
    at take (D:\Code\test\AWS-Dashboards\node_modules\@smithy\smithy-client\dist-cjs\object-mapping.js:44:9)
    at se_GetMetricDataCommand (D:\Code\test\AWS-Dashboards\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-connect\dist-cjs\protocols\Aws_restJson1.js:1984:52)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async D:\Code\test\AWS-Dashboards\node_modules\@smithy\middleware-serde\dist-cjs\serializerMiddleware.js:12:21
```

The code I've written looks like this and from what I can tell is correct

```
const metricData = await connectClient.send(new GetMetricDataCommand({
InstanceId: INSTANCE_ID,
StartTime: '1692162000',  //hardcoded time values to rule out conversion code
EndTime: '1692162005', // //hardcoded time values to rule out conversion code
HistoricalMetrics: metricsToFetch,
Groupings: ["CHANNEL", "QUEUE"],
Filters: {
    Channels: ["VOICE"],
    Queues: allQueueIds
}
```

}));

Here is what the request body looks like

```
{
  InstanceId: '25be8167-xxxx',
  StartTime: 1679121600,
  EndTime: 1679207999,
  HistoricalMetrics: [
    { Name: 'ABANDON_TIME', Unit: 'SECONDS', Statistic: 'AVG' },
    {
      Name: 'AFTER_CONTACT_WORK_TIME',
      Unit: 'SECONDS',
      Statistic: 'AVG'
    },
    { Name: 'API_CONTACTS_HANDLED', Unit: 'COUNT', Statistic: 'SUM' }
  ],
  Groupings: [ 'CHANNEL', 'QUEUE' ],
  Filters: {
    Channels: [ 'VOICE' ],
    Queues: [
      '4ca11bba-xxx-c0a0e11f0833',
      'd9a08b43-xxx-48c857e7dcbe',
      'f029944b-xx-abb8-6f7a9be0e4c2'
    ]
  }
}
```

Other endpoints in the same code work correctly

I'm using the V3 Javascript SDK

Any ideas or assistence at this point would be greatly appreciated